# iOS application cannot access downloaded file when relaunched - UUID changes

Tags: ios

I've been debugging a problem where my app successfully downloads a file and copies it to the Documents directory. Lately the app cannot open the downloaded file on subsequent launches of the app. I've been printing out file URLs and this is what I see when the file is initially downloaded and opened:

```
unzipped /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9AC69C00-228E-482F-99D8-DD8F214FCE88/Documents/3.atcase to 
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9AC69C00-228E-482F-99D8-DD8F214FCE88/Library/Application Support/thebundleID/current-case
```

You can see the UUIDs are the same, but when I launch the app again I see this:

```
couldn't unzip /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9AC69C00-228E-482F-99D8-DD8F214FCE88/Documents/3.atcase to 
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C18E7EFA-C0D0-4213-AF85-F5BC0D2A4207/Library/Application Support/thebundleID/current-case
```

This time the UUIDs appear to be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will say tentatively that the answer is yes, the UUID used in the application container folder does seem to change every time the app is run, though I'd love to have some confirmation from a more experienced developer.

The solution to my problem was straightforward: Do not store absolute file URLs in the database. The URLs for the files are now constructed relative to the Documents directory URL every time the app is run. Since I name the files in a regular way, there is no need to store URLs anyway.